# Find seed from previously-run code in R? How many possibilities are there?

Tags: r, random

I forgot to use set.seed myself in R and I'm trying to figure out what the seed was set to.

Anybody know how many possibilities there are?

I'm currently using the code below to generate 100 random values for each seed to check whether the list matches rand100, the 100 random values I'm trying to match.

```
t0= Sys.time()
for (i in 600000:1000000){

  set.seed(i)
  rand = runif(100,0,1)
  if (!(all.equal(rand100,rand) > 0)){
    print("match found!")
    print(i)
    break
  }

  t1= Sys.time()

  if(t1-t0>50){

    print("timeout")
    print(i)
    break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Random.html
...

> Initially, there is no seed; a new one is created from the current time and the process ID when one is required. Hence different sessions will give different simulation results, by default. However, the seed might be restored from a previous session if a previously saved workspace is restored.

... it depends on the time and process ID. I guess this situation cannot be recreated by anyone.
If you can, retrace your steps discard your current results and start over.
Don't waste your time with finding a needle in a hay stack. Even if you have 100 matches you are still not sure that it is the same seed.